# Android Room Database Delete Query Not Removing Any Rows

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I have created a Room database to store messages in a chat app and have defined the table like so:

```
@Entity(tableName = "message_table")
public class Message {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;

    @NonNull
    public String body;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "phone_number")
    public String phoneNumber;

    public Message(String body, String phoneNumber) {
        this.body = body;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

And when I query for all messages for a given phone number, it can retrieve them perfectly (Using the following query):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM message_table WHERE phone_number = :phoneNumber LIMIT 50")
LiveData<List<Message>> getMessagesByNumber(String phoneNumber);
```

But, when I try to remove all messages associated to the exact same phone number using the following command, I get 0 rows deleted every time:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM message_table WHERE phone_number = :phoneNumber")
int delete(String phoneNumber);
```

Am I missing something here? I have looked around but can't seem to find a solution to this. (And I have quadruple-checked that the phone number used in both the Select and Delete calls is 100% the same string).

Comment: can you upload your DB initialise code, like from where you calling your delete query?
confirm 1 more thing that you are actually doing it in  background thread?

Comment: @Faisal Thanks for that comment! It was the background thread. I was trying to delete from the UI thread. I moved my repository delete function to use an AsyncTask for the delete call and it fixed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Faisal's comment on the question. I was forgetting to run my delete method in a background thread.

I moved my delete code to an AsyncTask and it now works. Here is the repository function task:

```
private static class deleteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private MessageDao mAsyncTaskDao;
    private String mPhoneNumber = null;

    public deleteAsyncTask(MessageDao dao) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    public deleteAsyncTask(MessageDao dao, String phoneNumber) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
        mPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if (mPhoneNumber == null) {
            mAsyncTaskDao.deleteAll();
        }
        else {
            mAsyncTaskDao.delete(mPhoneNumber);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```